# Referencing journald fields when forwarding messages to syslog-ng

Tags: syslog, systemd, syslog-ng, journald

How can I change my syslog-ng template so that when the log originates from a systemd service / unit, the log message will include the unit's name?

Using `${PROGRAM}` just shows the name of the executable that the systemd service called / that the message originated from. journald seems to have a field for this information: `_SYSTEMD_UNIT`, but referencing that in my syslog-ng template seems to be insufficient.

**Background on my setup:**

I'm running Debian Jessie and have created systemd services to manage Docker containers. The applications in these containers log to stdout / stderr, which subsequently ends up in log files controlled by journald.

I use syslog-ng (version 3.5.6-2) to forward my logs to loggly and papertrail (comparing them right now). Since I'm running Debian Jessie, I configured journald to forward log messages to syslog by setting `ForwardToSyslog=yes` in `journald.conf`.

**Problem:**

The default templates for loggly and papertrail include `${PROGRAM}` in each log message, which is the name of the 'executable' that generated the message. However, in my setup, the executable called is `docker` for all of my containers. Thus, the name of the executable is useless for helping me filter logs and identify logs originating from specific containers.

**Notes:**

syslog-ng documentation notes that there is a `systemd-journal` driver, which seems to provide additional variables. However, that driver doesn't seem to be available in Debian Jessie's version of syslog-ng (3.5.6-2)

Comment: What's the point of exporting logs to external syslog just to emulate the structured logging behavior of journald which already have necessary information?

Answer (score 1):

You can find somewhat newer syslog-ng packages (that includes the systemd-journal driver) for Debian Jessie in the repository of a syslog-ng developer at https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:laszlo_budai:syslog-ng

I'm not sure that this will make the field available in syslog-ng (unless it is translated somewhere to _COMM or SYSLOG-IDENTIFIER, see http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/source-read-receive-and-collect-log-messages/systemd-journal-collecting-messages-from-the-systemd-journal-system-log-storage ), but if you do need it, open a Gitub issue at https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng

Regards, 
Robert

Answer (score 1):

I'm also referring journald fields that came from docker, basically you'll have to prepend `.journald.` at the field name, eg.

```
...
template("<$PRI>1 ${ISODATE} ${HOST} ${.journald.CONTAINER_TAG:--} ${PID:--} ${.journald.CONTAINER_ID:--} - ${MSG}\n")
```

Then it works like a charm

```
<134>1 2018-06-14T10:29:08+00:00 typerpc-3 alpine-02.1.vj6qhqulxkkojb9uatd3v08ar 1015 ef4e25bad3a3 - mg 2
```